# Why do ants feel more difficult to climb when height increases?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, biology

I have noticed that whenever an ant (carrying something) climbs a vertical wall, it easily climbs the lower part of the wall but as the height increases, the ant finds it difficult to climb and at even more height, it gets unbalanced and falls on the ground. I think it must be some downward force which increases with height and in the case of ant, there is only gravitational force acting downward but it is invariant with such small height differences. What makes them fall? Why don't they fall at lower heights?

Comment: Could it be that they get tired?

Comment: No, they fall and they again start to climb, they do this repeatedly.

Comment: Can you link to a (preferably high quality) video where we could see this occur? I'd like to see the wall structure.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot as it is very difficult to find any ant at the place where I am currently living.

Comment: I found a related video on YouTube - https://youtu.be/osEJEJbM1tg

Comment: I think you're anthopormophizing the ants, and not correctly assigning reasons here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be more about biomechanics than physics.  Perhaps try asking it on [Biology.SE].

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with getting tired considering an ant can carry 10-50 times their weight. The ability to climb a vertical wall involves a complicated combination of adhesion and friction between the ant's legs and the wall. See this: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0141269#:~:text=Ants%20are%20able%20to%20climb,and%204th%20tarsal%20segments. I suspect the reason for your observation is the load it was carrying was such that that combination was insufficient to keep the ant on the wall.  Credit persistence for continuing to try.

Answer (score 4):

Out of thin air suggestions:

1. The ant climbing gets tired in some specific regard (e.g. particular muscles). Falling and walking on level surface gives it time to recover somewhat.
2. The wall surface structure / humidity / slope / etc gradually changes with height making for the ant harder to climb
3. The ant has some more or less constant probability to fall from this particular wall in an unit of time. Climbing higher, it builds up a probability exposition and the probability of climbing to the top is rather low, but hopefully more than 0. A hint about this may be the distribution of the heights where ants fall.
4. Specific wind profile in height (the higher, the stronger wind).

Edit: as there is already a video, in the first seconds it is clear that the wall is not uniform in height. It has damaged paint and finish at the bottom and is in rather good (read: smooth) condition at the top, just like the walls like to be. The point 2 is probably the most important.

Comment: I like point number 3 @fraxinus

Comment: Agreed, point number 3 was very amusing and nice, . But i think the most likely answer is the most simple and uninteresting one i.e. point number 1

Comment: @silverrahul I rather doubt that, seeing as ants can and do carry large loads for distances many multiples of a wall height without tiring.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft My guess would be that this particular wall must be made of some material which is harder for ants to grip.